# Reading ints from serial port Arduino

Tags: c, arrays, arduino, serial-port

I've done a C program that writes an integer array into the Arduino:

```
// ...
FILE* file;
file = fopen("/dev/ttyuSB0","w");
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    fprintf(file, "%d ", rgb[i]);
}
fclose(file);
// ...
```

How can I do from my arduino code (.ino) to catch the three integers from the file?

```
while (Serial.available() > 0) {

    // What can I do here ???

}
```

Comment: `fprintf(file, "%d ", rgb[i]);` writes _text_.  Try just catching text and then convert to `int`.  Suggest using a non-space delimiter to know when the end of the textual representation of a number is complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read the data and put it into a buffer. After you encounter a `' '` character you terminate the string inside the buffer and convert it into an int.
When you do this three times you have read all three ints.

```
const uint8_t buff_len = 7; // buffer size
char buff[buff_len]; // buffer
uint8_t buff_i = 0; // buffer index

int arr[3] = {0,0,0}; // number array
uint8_t arr_i = 0; // number array index

void loop() {
    while (Serial.available() > 0) {
        char c = Serial.read();
        if (buff_i < buff_len-1) { // check if buffer is full
            if (c == ' ') { // check if got number terminator
                buff[buff_i++] = 0; // terminate the string
                buff_i = 0; // reset the buffer index
                arr[arr_i++] = atoi(buff); // convert the string to int
                if (arr_i == 3) { // if got all three numbers
                    arr_i = 0; // reset the number array index

                    // do something with the three integers
                }
            }
            else if (c == '-' || ('0' <= c && c <= '9')) // if negative sign or valid digit
                buff[buff_i++] = c; // put the char into the buffer
        }
    }
    // maybe do some other stuff
}
```

Or if you don't mind blocking code<sup>[1]</sup> you can use builtin [`ParseInt`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/ParseInt).

```
void loop() {
    while (Serial.available() > 0) {
        arr[0] = Serial.parseInt();
        arr[1] = Serial.parseInt();
        arr[2] = Serial.parseInt();
        Serial.read(); // read off the last space

        // do something with the three integers
    }
    // maybe do some other stuff, but might be blocked by serial read
}
```

<sup>[1] If your computer has a hiccup and doesn't send all the data at once, your Arduino code will just wait for data and won't be doing anything else. Read more [here](https://hackingmajenkoblog.wordpress.com/2016/02/01/reading-serial-on-the-arduino/).</sup>